# Website look non responsive or zoom out on mobile screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my client website that I made responsive a few days ago.

Site url: [grohair.sparkpointdigital.com](http://grohair.sparkpointdigital.com/)

It working perfect responsive when we resize browser screen or testing on other responsive checker tools but when we check the site on real mobile devices it not work well look like media queries are working but site take wide screen ( Zoom out).. one can check by itself site is live [grohair.sparkpointdigital.com](http://grohair.sparkpointdigital.com)

I know meta viewport tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

but it is there ..

Yes I also testing this on other server  [abhishekbhandari.com/grohair](http://abhishekbhandari.com/grohair)

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Hey thanks for reply as i said i already using it you can check by yourself too..

Comment: I know you have a viewport but use the one @defcon2 suggested

Comment: i am using the same @lucky , blag solve my problem thanks for your instant support guys

Comment: @Abhi next time please make your url link to your site and make use of ``Your tag here`` for the html tag

Comment: Sure i will take care of it thanks anyway..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the fist version of the CSS on http://grohair.sparkpointdigital.com/css/index.css you got this lines :

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 1164px;
    padding-top: 36px;
}
```

Aka : "I want my website to be at least 1164px width". => just remove the `min-width` line and it'll magically work...

If you lock the width, bootstrap will not be able to scale you content

Comment: THanks Blag,  it works but i am bit confused i added min-width:auto,  on priority that work on desktop browsers.. i am such a jerk seriously such a big mistake..   appreciate your help :)

Comment: @blag where do you see that code?

Comment: @LuckyChingi inspected the code of the url given by OP (maybe erase by an edit)

Comment: did you check this link http://grohair.sparkpointdigital.com/?

Comment: i removed the code @blag thanks for your help don't know who vote down your anwser  i thumbs up one ..@lucky it was inside index.css file

Comment: @Abhi when using bootstrap, don't set min-width on body, it'll more likely break everything... ; try using the default bootstrap class ;)

Comment: @LuckyChingi yes, it was on this, but patched by OP before you saw it I think ;)

Comment: thanks @blag actually these are the css using by the developer who made this website , i only make new css file that one is custom.css

Comment: @LuckyChingi edited, better like that, thanks ;)

Comment: @blag how did you think the votes turned positive :)

Comment: can anyone check this site on iphone please...grohair.sparkpointdigital.com

Comment: @Abhi http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://grohair.sparkpointdigital.com I don't have an iPhone but seem ok on this kind of thing...